# Have posts included on a page that share same category

Tags: posts, pages

I'm new to Wordpress so please bear with me.  I have created a site with two levels of hierarchy: top level and secondary level.  The secondary pages are grouped below corresponding top level pages.

I see that page content is retrieved using page.php.  I also see from page.php that the existence of content is tested by `have_posts()` and retrieved using `the_post()`.

How could I achieve having two different types of content on the the same page: "static" or evergreen page content at the top, and posts sharing the same category underneath?  I have Googled this all day and not found a satisfactory answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Please ask one question a time.

Answer (score 1):

> (…) are pages in fact posts?

You won't think what every thing is a post *type* in WordPress: Posts, Pages, Links, Nav Menu items... The same goes for Terms, Categories and other things, which are *built in* Taxonomies.

You can take a look at it with adding the following very late in your theme (the footer for example).

```
echo '<pre>'.var_export( wp_list_pluck( $GLOBALS['wp_post_types'], '_builtin' ), true ).'</pre>';
```

> (…) "static" or evergreen page content at the top, and posts sharing the same category underneath (…)

You're searching for [»Sticky« posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts).

Comment: Thanks for responding.  When I add your code to my footer, all post types resolve as NULL.  Also, I looked at sticky posts.  This only applies to the home/front page, no?  I would like to have a mixture of static and post content on every page on my site.

Comment: @dylanmac Fixed the var dump (forgot an underscore). Ad sticky posts, you can include them in every query. Just read the link complete.